# How can I get a script to run constantly on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, script, cron, launchd

I would like to do this: When the application VLC is open and I press the space bar, it pauses the video and an itunes starts to play. Then spacebar again would resume the workout video and pause my song.

Is there a way to do this on mac? Maybe using an actionscript or else?

Ex:

IF (VLC open and spacebar pressed)
{ play this song on itunes}
else
{ pause the song }

Answer (score 0):

This is possible since you can use macruby's bridge support to control itunes and VLC's interfaces over TCP. You can find the required material from these links

http://merbist.com/2010/01/17/controlling-itunes-with-macruby/

https://github.com/arcresu/vlcrc

Don't expect the answer to be as short as you believed. You will have to do the coding yourself as I don't have time enough to make the code and to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution in Applescript that could be triggered by a simple shortcut:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is stopped then
        playpause
    else
        playpause
        tell application "VLC" to activate
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke space
    end if
end tell
```